# How to associate stats printings to m5ops in FS mode of Gem5?

Tags: gem5

In SE mode, it's much easier to associate each stats printing to its corresponding m5op.

However, in FS mode where there are [multiple](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.m5.users/18824) (tens or even hundreds of) stats printings take place in the same 'stats.txt' file; How can we identify the following:

Which of the stats printing corresponds to what?

OR

At least, which of the stats printings are the sequel of m5ops invoked by a user?

Answer (score 0):

Each stats dump is wrapped with:

```
---------- Begin Simulation Statistics ----------
sim_seconds                                  0.000001                       # Number of seconds simulated
sim_ticks                                        1000                       # Number of ticks simulated
...
---------- End Simulation Statistics   ----------
```

In full system the only time the simulator dumps stats is on exit, all of the rest are driven by your runscript and your application. So all stats blocks except the last one, wrapped between Begin-End Simulation Statistics correspond to a dump issued by an m5op. If you need more accuracy as to which event caused which dump, you can check the pseudo_inst.cc file and add/modify it accordingly. This might be implemented in the newer versions, but I am not up to date on that.

Comment: According to the attached link in my question, I think we can not say that only one stats printing happens in FS mode (i.e., In full system the only time the simulator dumps stats is on exit). I Would say no.

Comment: And, this is the same to what I have experienced.

Comment: Anyways your pointing `pseudo_inst.cc` might be useful for me in future. Thanks